# dojo amd load jquery undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, dojo, amd

I'm being forced to use the dojo amd loader and I'm folding in another portion of the project that was written the majority jquery selectors.  I'm making a module to load in my jquery code but the first line is breaking.

question: how do I load jquery into a dojo module?

I've been searching around but can't seem to find this, I'm guessing its something simple...

```
define(['../../scripts/libs/jquery.js'], function($){
    "use strict";
$('#layers').click(function() {
    if ($('#layerMenu:visible').length > 0) {
        $('#layersMenu, #layersList').toggle();
        $('#basemapMenu, #bookmarkMenu').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('navHighlight');
        $('#basemap, #bookmarks').removeClass('navHighlight');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: where is the '$' and ')' missing?

Comment: You are reading `length` property of the String object not jQuery object => `('#layerMenu:visible').length` and missing `)` for the `.define()` function.

Comment: thx I got the missing '$' but I'm not seeing the missing ')' I've updated the code accordingly with my current updates

Comment: also remove the .js from the end of the file

Comment: Why are you using `define()` to create a new Dojo module... and not returning a value? I think you probably wanted `require()` instead.

Comment: @darien there were a few other functions inside this define that I omitted, but the point is well recieved I need to setup the return to send out necessary pieces  from the define. thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a look at this [link](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modules/)  what you need is to configure your dojo loader to load files from not only dojo location but other location.

Solution:

1) you put the jquery library inside dojo files which is not a good idea

2) as i mention before to tell dojo configuration to look for files in another place.

```
var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "/js/",
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
    packages: [
        { name: "dojo", location: "lib/dojo" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "lib/dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "lib/dojox" },
        { name: "my", location: "my", main: "app" },
        { name: "Jquery",location:"../../scripts/libs/"}
    ]
};
```

I would recommend to use full qualified path.

Comment: thx I had a feeling it was because of the dojoConfig, setting that up helped.  I'm using the ArcGIS library(built on top of dojo) and their examples don't use the dojoConfig, this is also what I was missing. Thx